# Number of non-isomorphic induced subgraphs of a graph

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-isomorphism

Given a simple undirected grap, how many induced subgraphs does it have that are not isomorphic to each other? (or in a descision version, does it have fewer than k non-isomorphic induced subgraphs).

Does anyone know the computational complexity of this problem? Are bounds known?

Comment: A related question seems to be: For a given n, how many graphs exists with n vertices such that no two are isomorphic.

Comment: The number of isomorphism classes of graphs on $n$ vertices is well-studied and known asymptotically to be $2^{\binom{n}{2}}/n!$ (exact asymptotic, not big-oh). Presumably for your question you want some further restriction, e.g. induced subgraphs on $k$ vertices (where $k$ could be part of the input)? Otherwise you can always get at least $n$ non-isomorphic induced subgraphs by considering subgraphs of different numbers of vertices. Finally, do you want to consider only *connected* induced subgraphs?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I do not only want to consider connected induced subgraphs. In the decision version, I consider k a part of the input.

Comment: I shouldn't have used $k$, because you already used that for the bound in the decision version. Let me try again: do you only want to consider induced subgraphs *with a given number of vertices*? If so, is the number of vertices part of the input?

Comment: No, I want to consider all induced subgraphs (it does not matter how many vertices they have).